# What is the correct usage of conditional and hypothetical?

Tags: conditionals

Is my translation correct in the following examples?

> If (when) I build a house I will buy furniture.
>
> 家を建てたら、家具を買う。
>
> If I built a house I would buy furniture.
>
> 家を建てたなら、家具を買った。
>
> If I build a house I will have a place to live.
>
> 家を建てると住む場所がある。
>
> If I build a house I will buy good furniture.
> 家を建てれば、良い家具を買う。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If (when) I build a house I will buy furniture.
>
> 家{いえ}を建{た}て**たら**、家具{かぐ}を買{か}う。

Correct.  That is an exemplary use of 「たら」 for a **specific and/or one-time-only** condition-consequence relationship.

In a real-life setting, however, the 「買う」 ending would sound quite blunt.  It would be more natural to say 「買うつもりです」、「買うと思{おも}います」, etc.

> If I built a house I would buy furniture.
>
> 家を建てた**なら**、家具を買った。

Ungrammatical and unnatural.  Why use the past tense 「買った」 here?  You have not bought the furniture yet.  Moreover, you have not even built/bought a house yet as you utter this line.

In a proper and natural use of 「なら」, the second half (the consequence part) would express some kind of opinion, judgement, wish, etc. of the speaker.  A verb phrase in the simple past tense (as 「家具を買った」) would generally not fit there.

A natural-sounding second half would be along the lines of:

「素敵{すてき}な家具をたくさん買いたいです」,

「イタリアまで家具を買いに行くつもりです」, etc.

> If I build a house I will have a place to live.
>
> 家を建てる**と**住{す}む場所{ばしょ}がある。

Nice try but sounds unnatural on the native level.  When native speakers see/hear the condition 「家を建てると」, we will naturally expect to see/hear that something will ***happen*** as a result of it.

The problem here is your verb choice of 「ある」, which is ***stative***.  It is too weak to make something sound like an "action".  Change it to 「できる」 and it will instantly satisfy the reader/listener's expectation of seeing/hearing about what would **happen** then.

> If I build a house I will buy good furniture.
>
> 家を建て**れば**、良{い}い家具を買う。

Grammatical but unnatural.  (Again, I am speaking on the native level because that is the ONLY level on which I can judge these things.  For all I know, your sentences might be graded as A+ in a Japanese-as-a-foreign-language class.)

「れば」 should be used to express a **constant and/or permanent** kind of condition-consequence relationship.

It might certainly be somewhat universal to buy furniture if you build a house, but buying "good" furniture is not, is it?  Buying "good" furniture is basically this particular speaker's desire.

As I stated in the beginning, 「たら」 would be a far better and more natural word choice here.

Comment: I got the idea about the second example from a famous song "もしも 私が家を建てたなら
小さな家を建てたでしょう"