# Usage of conditional なら

Tags: conditionals

Why is 建てる in the result clause in the past tense?  The answer from [What is the correct usage of conditional and hypothetical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43604/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-conditional-and-hypothetical) indicates that it should not be in the past.

> もしも 私が家を建てたなら
>
> 小さな家を建てたでしょう

Answer (score 2):

This is not "past tense" usage, it is rather more related to **aspect** (*in this case whether the speaker considers the action to be complete or incomplete*).

The difference between 建て**た**なら as compared to 建て**る**なら in your example could be conveyed through the English subjunctive mood like this:

> もしも私が家を建て**た**なら、小さな家を建て**た**でしょう

If I **were to build** a house, I **would build** a small house.

> 私が家を建て**る**なら、小さな家を建て**る**でしょう

If I **build** a house, I'**ll build** a small one.

Answer (score 0):

> Conditional clause: もしも 私が家を建てたなら
>
> Result clause: 小さな家を建てた(でしょう)

These Japanese sentences are natural, and we understand that the speaker didin't (has not) build the small house (or house itself), from the phrae "建てたでしょう"

Yes "建{た}てた" is the past form of the verb "建{た}てる."　The past form of a verb is used for the situation went unrealized in Japanese.

「もし僕が君だったら、そんなことはしなかった(でしょう)。」= If I were you, I would not do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to understand that usage of なら would be to see it as an imaginary situation.

> 建てたなら -> If I was in a situation where I built a house.
>   小さな家を建てたでしょう -> That house would probably be a small one.

It is a way to convey your thoughts/likes/dislikes.
It basically means that "If I was in situation A, B would be as such because knowing what kind of person I am, I know I wouldn't have had it any other way."

This can be used when reflecting on the decision of someone else.
For your example, it could be that your friend just built a big house, and then you tell him that if you were in his situation(just built a big house), it would be a small one.